# pgxpool's config.AfterRelease is not firing

Tags: go

I have the following code:

```
func (s *SqlServerDatabase) ConnectPool() {
    config, err := pgxpool.ParseConfig(s.Url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("config Database Fail")
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    config.AfterRelease = func(conn *pgx.Conn) bool {
        fmt.Println("After Releasing")
        return true
    }

    config.BeforeAquire = func(ctx context.Context, conn *pgx.Conn) bool {
        fmt.Println("Before Aquiring")
        return true
    }

    conn, err := pgxpool.ConnectConfig(context.Background(), config)

    s.PoolConn = conn
}

func (s *SqlServerDatabase) PoolQuery(query string) (pgx.Rows, error) {
    conn, err := s.PoolConn.Acquire(context.Background())

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Couldn't get a connection with the database. Reason %v", err)
    } else {
        // release the connection to the pool after using it
        defer conn.Release()

        results, err := conn.Query(context.Background(), query)

        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Couldn't execute query. Reason %v", err)
        } else {
            // show the results boy, you got it.
            fmt.Printf("%T\n", results)
        }
        return results, err
    }
    return nil, err
}
```

So :

- I create the connection in `ConnectPool`. thats where I set up the config and connect.
- Then In my query method I acquire one of the pools the `BeforeAcquire` method fires and prints.
- But the AfterRelease method never does.

I release the connection in the deferred call so I'm not sure why its not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code at [pgxpool/conn.go l.30](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/blob/ac2918b9a32454f04833395a7be31d1e136782f8/pgxpool/conn.go#L30) :

```golang
/*20*/ func (c *Conn) Release() {
             ...
/*30*/     if conn.IsClosed() || conn.PgConn().IsBusy() ||
              conn.PgConn().TxStatus() != 'I' ||
              (now.Sub(res.CreationTime()) > c.p.maxConnLifetime) {
               res.Destroy()
               return
           }

/* 'c.afterRelease' is checked and used only after that block */
```

So : under some conditions, the connection is detroyed right away, and `AfterRelease` is indeed never executed.

---

*note:* the code link reflects the state of the `master` branch on 2021-05-05.